# Heroku is giving me 404 error, only renders "Unkown path"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, meteor, routes

I'm trying to deploy my application to heroku, however when I try to open the link to it, the only thing being rendered is "unkown path", erros being "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

I kept checking the routes files as much as I could and I can't see what doesn't work here. This is how the index.js file looks like

```
import route from './router.js';

import Login from '../ui/pages/user/Login';
import Home from '../ui/Home';
import Register from '../ui/pages/user/Register';
import PostCreate from '../ui/pages/post/PostCreate';
import PostList from '../ui/pages/post/PostList';
import PostEdit from '../ui/pages/post/PostEdit';

route('/', Home, {}, {
    name: 'home'
  });
  route('/login', Login, {}, {
    name: 'login'
  });
  route('/register', Register, {}, {
    name: 'register'
  });
  route('/post/create', PostCreate, {}, {
    name: 'post.create'
  });
  route('/post/list', PostList, {}, {
    name: 'post.list'
  });
  route('/post/edit/:_id', PostEdit, {}, {
    name:'post.edit'
  });
```

And this is the router.js file

```
import { createRouter } from 'meteor/cultofcoders:meteor-react-routing';
import App from '/imports/ui/App.jsx';

export default createRouter(App);
```

Could it just be an issue regarding the routing package I'm using?

Comment: Just to clarify- is it the default Heroku 404 page, or the 404 route from your application?

Comment: It's from my application. This is the link to it, in case you want to check it out https://onboarding4cultofcoders.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Cool, thanks- and does it work when you use [**`heroku local`**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local)

Comment: Hmm the console is giving me an error saying " [WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile' " ? This was actually the first time I tried heroku local, not exactly sure what it means?

Comment: Ah yeah, so for Heroku you need something called a [**`Procfile`**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile). It stores all your project meta, most importantly the engine you are using (e.g. Node), the command for build script, and path of the entry point.

Comment: I would recommend that you follow the [**_Getting Started_**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/start) guide for Node.js. There's just a couple of small steps you are missing, but once your project runs locally with no hitches, it should run fine on the deploy. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Ook, thank you! I'll get on it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are using the "wrong" router. cultofcoders:meteor-react-routing seems to not have been maintained in the past 2 years which is huge in terms of react routing. Would you be interested to try `"react-router": "^5.0.0"` with `"react-router-dom": "^5.0.0"` then you have something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Component1 from '.....'
import Component2 from '.....'

const Main = location => {
  return (
      <Switch location={location.location}>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Component1} />
        <Route exact path='/something' component={Component2} />
        <Route exact path='/something/:id' component={Component2} /> // route with param
        <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage} />
        ...........
      </Switch>)
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I used what you said, and it worked. Thanks for your feedback.